# CTE Select Order By Dynamically column name

Tags: sql-server

```
;with cte as select * from customer
```

the select cte order by passing parameter

```
if(@orderby=1)
  begin
    select * from cte order by name
  end
 else if (@oderby=2)
  begin
     select * from cte order by applydate   
  end
 else
    begin
     select * from cte order by customeramount
    end
```

this following error invalid object cte How to Solve this sql query

I have to Solve The Problem

The code is

```
 SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy WHEN 0 THEN Name ELSE null END , CASE  @OrderBy WHEN 1 THEN  Code ELSE null END ,CASE @OrderBy  WHEN 2 THEN  ApplyAmountTotal ELSE null END ,CASE @OrderBy WHEN 3 THEN ApplyDate ELSE null END
```

Comment: That's not how the `with` clause works. You can't just declare a CTE and then use it wherever you want in your TSQL script. It can only be used as part of another query(set). If you need to reuse it at arbitary points later, make it a temp table (or table variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use case as below:

```
;With cte as 
(   select * from customer  )
Select * from cte 
    Order by (case when @orderby=1 then [name]
                   when @orderby=2 then applydate
                   else customerAmount end )
```

Comment: I have excute but i find error "Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type."

Answer (score 0):

`name`, `applydate`, `customerAmount` are not the same data type, 
then you could use 3 `CASE ...END` clauses like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
ORDER BY        
        CASE
          WHEN @oderby = 1 THEN name          
          ELSE ''
        END,
        CASE
          WHEN @oderby = 2 THEN applydate
          ELSE '1900-01-01'
        END,
        CASE
          WHEN @oderby NOT IN (1,2) THEN customerAmount
          ELSE 1
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am find the Answer

```
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy WHEN 0 THEN Name ELSE null END , CASE  @OrderBy WHEN 1 THEN  Code ELSE null END ,CASE @OrderBy  WHEN 2 THEN  ApplyAmountTotal ELSE null END ,CASE @OrderBy WHEN 3 THEN ApplyDate ELSE null END
```